# Удалить часть текста из ссылки C#

Tags: c#, строки

Есть `string` url , в который с пользователь вводит url по типу `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` , как сделать так чтобы удалить `https://`, string Remove только по индексу

upd : нашел способ `Replace("https://","")` , но выглядит так себе)

Comment: ну еще есть Substring

Comment: "но выглядит так себе" - что Вас не устраивает?

Comment: @Igor да думал есть способ по типу куда просто пишешь текст который хочешь убрать - и его отпиливает оттуда , почему не сделать string Remove и по тексту так же?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот вообще каноничный способ отпилить любую схему от любой ссылки

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");
string withoutScheme = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Scheme, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
Console.WriteLine(withoutScheme);
```

Вывод

```
ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```